# How does React.useState triggers re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above example whenever `setCount(count + 1)` is invoked a re-render  happens. I am curious to learn the flow.

I tried looking into the source code. I could not find any reference of `useState` or other hooks at [github.com/facebook/react](https://github.com/facebook/react/search?q=useState&unscoped_q=useState).

I installed `react@next` via `npm i react@next` and found the following at `node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js`

```js
function useState(initialState) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useState(initialState);
}
```

On tracing back for `dispatcher.useState()`, I could only find the following ...

```js
function resolveDispatcher() {
  var dispatcher = ReactCurrentOwner.currentDispatcher;
  !(dispatcher !== null) ? invariant(false, 'Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.') : void 0;
  return dispatcher;
}
```

```js
var ReactCurrentOwner = {
  /**
   * @internal
   * @type {ReactComponent}
   */
  current: null,
  currentDispatcher: null
};
```

I wonder where can I find `dispatcher.useState()` implementation and learn how it triggers re-render when <s>`setState`</s> `setCount` is invoked.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I would believe it is behaviour of `fiber` so said Reacts core algorithm. They describe it as, `React Fiber is an ongoing reimplementation of React's core algorithm.` https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture I would believe `userState` -creates Object and pointer in `fiber` an when ever it value changes it triggers re-render. This is just a guess but I would expect something similiar to this.

Comment: Actually, hooks in react use the useState to invoke the state update which is similar to setState. So whenever state is changed comonent willl be re-rendered.

Answer (score 11):

The key in understanding this is the following paragraph from the [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components)

> **How does React associate Hook calls with components?**
>
> React keeps track of the currently rendering component. Thanks to the Rules of Hooks, we know that Hooks are only called from React components (or custom Hooks — which are also only called from React components).
>
> There is an internal list of “memory cells” associated with each component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data. When you call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to the next one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get independent local state.

(This also explains the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Hooks need to be called unconditionally in the same order, otherwise the association of *memory cell* and hook is messed up.)

Let's walk through your counter example, and see what happens. For simplicity I will refer to the [compiled development React source code](https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.development.js) and [React DOM source code](https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js), both version 16.13.1.

The example starts when the component mounts and `useState()` (defined on line 1581) is called for the first time.

```
function useState(initialState) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useState(initialState);
}
```

As you have noticed, this calls `resolveDispatcher()` (defined on line 1546). The `dispatcher` refers internally to the component that's currently being rendered. Within a component you can (if you dare to get fired), have a look at the dispatcher, e.g. via

```
console.log(React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher.current)
```

If you apply this in case of the counter example, you will notice that the `dispatcher.useState()` refers to the [react-dom](https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js) code. When the component is first mounted, `useState` refers to the one defined on line 15986 which calls `mountState()`. Upon re-rendering, the dispatcher has changed and the function `useState()` on line 16077 is triggered, which calls `updateState()`. Both methods, `mountState()` on line 15352 and `updateState()` on line 15371, return the `count, setCount` pair.

Tracing `ReactCurrentDispatcher` gets quite messy. However, the fact of its existence is already enough to understand how the re-rendering happens. The *magic* happens behind the scene. As the FAQ states, React keeps track of the currently rendered component. This means, `useState()` *knows* which component it is attached to, how to find the state information and how to trigger the re-rendering.

Comment: "useState() knows which component it is attached to, how to find the state information and how to trigger the re-rendering." - the question is, we are curious how does it know? curious about the implementation & the magic behind!

Answer (score 5):

I also tried to understand the logic behind *useState* in a very simplified and basic manner, if we just look into its basic functionalities, excluding optimizations and async behavior, then we found that it is basically doing 4 things in common,

1. maintaining of State, primary work to do
2. re-rendering of the component through which it get called so that caller component can get the latest value for state
3. as it caused the re-rendering of the caller component it means it must maintain the instance or context of that component too, which also allows us to use *useState* for multiple component at once.
4. as we are free to use as many *useState* as we want inside our component that means it must maintain some identity for each *useState* inside the same component.

keeping these things in mind I come up with the below snippet

```
const Demo = (function React() {
  let workInProgress = false;
  let context = null;

  const internalRendering = (callingContext) => {
    context = callingContext;
    context();
  };

  const intialRender = (component) => {
    context = component;
    workInProgress = true;
    context.state = [];
    context.TotalcallerId = -1; // to store the count of total number of useState within a component
    context.count = -1; // counter to keep track of useStates within component
    internalRendering(context);
    workInProgress = false;
    context.TotalcallerId = context.count;
    context = null;
  };

  const useState = (initState) => {
    if (!context) throw new Error("Can only be called inside function");

     // resetting the count so that it can maintain the order of useState being called

    context.count =
      context.count === context.TotalcallerId ? -1 : context.count; 

    let callId = ++context.count;

    // will only initialize the value of setState on initial render
    const setState =
      !workInProgress ||
      (() => {
        const instanceCallerId = callId;
        const memoizedContext = context;
        return (updatedState) => {
          memoizedContext.state[instanceCallerId].value = updatedState;
          internalRendering(memoizedContext);
        };
      })();

    context.state[callId] = context.state[callId] || {
      value: initState,
      setValue: setState,
    };

    return [context.state[callId].value, context.state[callId].setValue];
  };

  return { useState, intialRender };
})();

const { useState, intialRender } = Demo;

const Component = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState("hello");

  const changeCount = () => setCount(100);
  const changeGreeting = () => setGreeting("hi");

  setTimeout(() => {
    changeCount();
    changeGreeting();
  }, 5000);

  return console.log(`count ${count} name ${greeting}`);
};

const anotherComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(50);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("World");

  const changeCount = () => setCount(500);
  const changeValue = () => setValue("React");

  setTimeout(() => {
    changeCount();
    changeValue();
  }, 10000);

  return console.log(`count ${count} name ${value}`);
};
intialRender(Component);
intialRender(anotherComponent);
```

here *useState* and *initialRender* are taken from Demo. *intialRender* is use to call the components initially, it will initialize the *context* first and then on that context set the *state* as an empty array (there are multiple *useState* on each component so we need array to maintain it) and also we need *counter* to make count for each *useState*, and *TotalCounter* to store total number of *useState* being called for each component.

Answer (score 4):

`setState` is a method on the `Component/PureComponent` class, so it will do whatever is implemented in the `Component` class (including calling the `render` method).

`setState` offloads the state update to `enqueueSetState` so the fact that it's bound to this is really only a consequence of using classes and extending from `Component`. Once, you realize that the state update isn't actually being handled by the component itself and the `this` is just a convenient way to access the state update functionality, then `useState` not being explicitly bound to your component makes much more sense.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I used `setState` in the second last sentence of the question. It was an unintentional typo, it should have been `setCount`. I have updated the question accordingly. Please feel free to update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

FunctionComponent is different. In the past, they are pure, simple. But now they have their own state.
It's easy to forget that react use createElement wrap all the JSX node, also includes FunctionComponent.

```
function FunctionComponent(){
  return <div>123</div>;
}
const a=<FunctionComponent/>
//after babel transform
function FunctionComponent() {
  return React.createElement("div", null, "123");
}

var a = React.createElement(FunctionComponent, null);
```

The FunctionComponent was passed to react. When setState is called, it's easy to re-render;