# React useState handler called TWICE

Tags: reactjs

Having such a simple React App:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {

  console.log("App")

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue("e.target.value")}
      />
      <button onClick={(e) => setInputValue(1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <h1>Render Count: {inputValue}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I'm getting initially (after the App loads):

> App

AND

> App

> App

on interaction -  when I click the button or type sth. in the input field.

My question is WHY does the `App` is printed TWICE in the second case (interaction)!? It's strange because the `inputValue` is ONLY changed ONCE on the first click/input but in the second interaction it stays the same, not changing anymore!

P.S.

It's NOT the case of the `react strict mode`! - In the *index.js* I have:

```
...
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
...
```

so I'm NOT using `react strict mode`!

Comment: One issue: `setInputValue("e.target.value")` should not be in double quotes.
Here is a exact replica of your code on codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fog-jmrsiv?file=/src/index.js

I can't reproduce two renders.

Comment: When I try out the example in a codesandbox, I get one console.log when I type a character into the input and a second one when I click the button. That looks absolutely correct to me. Is it different for you? If not, which of the two console.logs do you find confusing?

Answer (score 0):

When the component mounts, there is always one render.
Then when the state changes from 0 -> 1 there is another render.

When using the `useState` hook, it re-renders whenever a state value changes, not necessarily every time you call `setState` (which was the old behaviour). So every time you click after the first time, the state goes from 1 -> 1 and you get no re render because the value is the same.

Answer (score 0):

React setState causes re-render.

You can learn more about this behavior here: [How does React.useState triggers re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024488/how-does-react-usestate-triggers-re-render)